# How to call a bootstrap modal which is in a partial?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have that button which is

```
                    <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
                </li>
```

That `#MyModal` is inside a partial view  `Login` that has its `ActionResult` in the controller . How to call that modal from within clicking on Login?

Comment: Please add the contents of your partial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than data-attributes give your anchor element an id:

```
<a href="#" id='myanchor'>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
```

and then bind to the click event of that element in JavaScript:

```
  $('#myanchor').click(function(){
      $('#MyModal').modal('show'); 
  });
```

Comment: I've done that, but I think the event can't find the modal to show or start, because the modal isn't in the same cshtml file.

Comment: If the DOM element doesn't exist then it obviously won't work. To get the element in the DOM you need to render your partial somewhere in the page -> `@Html.Partial("_<PartialName>")`

Comment: sorry I was wrong, I had to get it back as you said, thank you !